# html navigation menu dropdown showing only last menu item

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a menu bar which has child menu drop down. when I hover over the parent menu item it shows only last sub menu item in drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I used `position: absolute;` attribute for drop-down ul element.